# Python 3 can't find my own module in same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

[image]

[image]

```
/database/frontend
/database/backend
```

Both files are in the same directory with no sub directories or folders but still can't import backend in front end 
I have tried setting the `PYTHONPATH`;
`sys.append() method`; using `from . Import backend` but still cant figure it out

Comment: Did you make some `__init__.py` files?

Comment: What are the files in `/database/backend`? Also what code are you using to import the module?

Comment: The filename should be `backend.py` instead of `backend`. In that way the frontend.py can `import backend`

Comment: @cricket_007 no I didnt make them but they are in same directory ,is it necessary?

Comment: @Jachdich import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Python-Projects\\database-application")
print(sys.path)
from tkinter import *
import backend

Comment: like import backend.py ? but it didnt cause any changes @shuva

Comment: Hmm. If I remember right you can put your module in `[python dir]/Lib/site-packages` to import it with no extra code. Don't rely on this being right though. I'll test it in a bit.

Comment: @Jachdich i am using anaconda so do i have to put it in  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages ?

Comment: @2012v I don't know about Anaconda. It's worth a try, then just `from [module name] import backend` if I'm right.

Comment: @Jachdich not working

Comment: @2012v OK, I don't know then I'm afraid.

Comment: @2012v, I mentioned that the filename should be `backend.py` . But in the code you should only `import backend` not `import backend.py`.

Comment: You cannot import `ipynb` files, only `py` files. Please read about packages. Yes, the init files are required https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages